# Promise.all seems to be returning prematurely. What am I missing here?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm running the code below in an AWS Lambda function (Node 4.3 runtime). Promise.all seems to be returning prematurely, as the deleteSnapshot action is not running. I'm relatively new to Node.js, so I'm certain I'm missing something obvious here. But what is it?

```
EC2.describeSnapshots(searchParams).promise().then((data) => {
    Promise.all(data.Snapshots.map((snapshot) => {
       var deleteParams = {SnapshotId: snapshot.SnapshotId};
       console.log('Deleting ' + snapshot.SnapshotId + ' pertaining to AMI ' + event.detail.requestParameters.imageId);
       return EC2.deleteSnapshot(deleteParams).promise();
    })).then(context.done());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're calling `context.done()` immediately and then passing whatever that returns to `Promise.all().then()`.  That's not what you want or intend to do.  You need to pass a function reference to `.then()`, not the result of calling `context.done()`.  You could fix it like this:

```
EC2.describeSnapshots(searchParams).promise().then((data) => {
    return Promise.all(data.Snapshots.map((snapshot) => {
       var deleteParams = {SnapshotId: snapshot.SnapshotId};
       console.log('Deleting ' + snapshot.SnapshotId + ' pertaining to AMI ' + event.detail.requestParameters.imageId);
       return EC2.deleteSnapshot(deleteParams).promise();
    })).then(() => context.done());    // <== Note change here
});
```

To explain a little more, when you have this code:

```
 Promise.all(...).then(context.done())
```

That is similar to this:

```
 let temp = context.done();
 Promise.all(...).then(temp);
```

So, you can clearly see that you're calling `context.done()` way too early.  Instead, you need to put `context.done()` in some sort of function wrapper so you can pass that wrapper function reference to `.then()`.  There are actually multiple ways to do that - I showed using an arrow function above, but it could also be done with `.bind()` as in

```
  })).then(context.done.bind(context));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all()` returns a promise. You need to return that promise from the `then()` otherwise the first `then()` returns undefined and `context.done()` will be called too soon.

```
EC2.describeSnapshots(searchParams).promise().then((data) => {
    return Promise.all(data.Snapshots.map((snapshot) => {
    // etc.
```